# What does concat without an object in Rails/Ruby do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I came upon the below code somewhere and can see that it will render a partial using some block. But what does the last part with the `concat` do?

```
  def method(stuff="example", &block)

    content = render(:partial => 'some_partial',
        :locals => { :content => capture(&block) }
    )
    concat(content)
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenates the strings you pass it before rendering them

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat

Answer (score 0):

The `concat` method is used to output text, when it is not within an output block such as `<%= %>`.